# GUI running without $XAUTHORITY being defined, but not for root

Tags: x11, display, xauth

I'm using CentOS 6, with Xfce as a desktop environment and have switched to `xdm` from `gdm` as a display manager.

However, after making this change, I am observing a very strange oddity: graphical applications can run without `$XAUTHORITY` being defined:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
$ echo $XAUTHORITY

$ zenity --error --text ".........."
$ echo $?
0
```

And yet, when I sudo:

```
$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for xxxxxx: 
# echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
# echo $XAUTHORITY

# zenity --error --text "........."
No protocol specified

(zenity:3793): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I thought both `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` need to be defined for a GUI to run, but this isn't happening. Does anyone have a clue as to what is going on?

**EDIT**:

It was suggested in the comments to inspect and use the value of `DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS_VALUE`, but:

```
$ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ypE50rEtQu,guid=7e2bc970a8ca43af3f7bb01000000255
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
$ sudo -s
# export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ypE50rEtQu,guid=7e2bc970a8ca43af3f7bb01000000255"
# echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
# echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ypE50rEtQu,guid=7e2bc970a8ca43af3f7bb01000000255
# zenity --error --text "..........."
No protocol specified

(zenity:16931): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Comment: @don_crissti, I use `xdm`, not `gdm`!

Comment: All right but have you checked whether your system uses `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` or not ?

Comment: @don_crissti, yea, `DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS_VALUE` is defined, but exporting it also doesn't work! (Adding this info to OP).

Comment: You have to run the (zenity/notify) command as the user currently active on `DISPLAY :0.0` e.g. `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dgVfhNaG5L,guid=e0fea52a090f19174e207c4854691ae1'  DISPLAY=:0.0 su don -c "zenity --error --text 'error'"`. Works fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **X**(7) overview man page (recommend reading the whole thing, by the way) tells us:

> The file from which Xlib extracts authorization data can be specified with the environment variable XAUTHORITY, and defaults to the file .Xauthority in the home directory.

So no, XAUTHORITY is not mandatory if you have your authorization file in the usual location. It's perfectly normal for X clients to work without it. Switching users can break it because the home directory is different, and setting the environment variable helps in that case.